# Java Event Handler Naming Convention

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have been struggling with this and cannot come up with a good convention to name event handlers. I have a project (spring integration) which has a inbound channel adaptor listening to various types of events. Events received are passed to a Router which then publishes it to a channel (a different channel for each type of event). We have a service activator listening to these channels which then consumes these events.

This is the naming convention we have now... For example, an event ORDER_CREATED is published to a channel named 'order-created-channel'. On the other end of the channel we have a service activator named OrderCreatedEventHandler. The OrderCreatedEventHandler sends a notification to the buyer for who the order is created. So the Event Handlers are named based on the type of event they are consuming/handling and not the activity they perform. But now I have a problem... I want to change the 'order-created-channel' to a publish subscribe channel and I want 2 service activators listening on it. One of the service activators should send a notification to the buyer and the other one should create an invoice for that order.

So it got me thinking... Should I not have those service activators end with the word 'EventHandlers'? Should I name them on the activity they are performing? Is there any convention for naming channels and beans that handle events?

Answer (score 0):

There's no general convention for naming; it's up to your organization.

My only general recommendation is to give endpoints an `id` (rather than omitting and letting the framework name the endpoint). Beyond that, it's up to you.